# Why does the address of QVector change when size() has not surpassed capacity() after calling QXYSeries::replace()?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qtcharts

I have a small test program that inserts values into a QVector. The QVector is reserved at start to have a minimum amount of memory allocated. I verify that the capacity is correct and that the size of the QVector does not surpass the capacity.

I observe that appending data to the QVector does not change the address of the first element.
All good this far.

I then use the replace() method of the QSplineSeries class to copy the data from the vector to the chart. I again check the address of the first element in the QVector after calling this method and to my surprise the address has changed!

This happens on every call to this method and I want to understand why this happens. I suspect maybe there's something related to Qt's container's implicit sharing, but I don't see why this should change the address of this container.

The example code and output is shown below.

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QtCharts/QChart>
#include <QtCharts/QChartView>
#include <QtCharts/QSplineSeries>
#include <memory>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    auto chart = std::make_unique<QtCharts::QChartView>(new QtCharts::QChart());
    chart->chart()->addSeries(new QtCharts::QSplineSeries);

    QVector<QPointF> vector;
    vector.reserve(1000);

    while (true) {
        vector.append(QPointF(0, 0));
        qDebug() << "1. Size: " << vector.size() << " Capacity: " << vector.capacity();
        qDebug() << "1. Address of first element: " << &vector[0];
        auto series = dynamic_cast<QtCharts::QSplineSeries*>(chart->chart()->series().at(0));
        series->replace(vector);
        qDebug() << "2. Size: " << vector.size() << " Capacity: " << vector.capacity();
        qDebug() << "2. Address of first element: " << &vector[0];
    }

    return a.exec();
}
```

**Output**

> 1. Size:  1  Capacity:  1000
> 2. Address of first element:  0x222725d61e8
> 3. Size:  1  Capacity:  1000
> 4. Address of first element:  0x222725dc0d8
> 5. Size:  2  Capacity:  1000
> 6. Address of first element:  0x222725dc0d8
> 7. Size:  2  Capacity:  1000
> 8. Address of first element:  0x222725d61e8
> 9. Size:  3  Capacity:  1000
> 10. Address of first element:  0x222725d61e8
> 11. Size:  3  Capacity:  1000
> 12. Address of first element:  0x222725dc0d8
> 13. Size:  4  Capacity:  1000
> 14. Address of first element:  0x222725dc0d8
> 15. Size:  4  Capacity:  1000
> 16. Address of first element:  0x222725d61e8
> 17. Size:  5  Capacity:  1000
> 18. Address of first element:  0x222725d61e8
> 19. Size:  5  Capacity:  1000
> 20. Address of first element:  0x222725dc0d8

[Link to the source code of the QSplineSeries::replace(QVector) call here](https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtcharts/src/charts/xychart/qxyseries.cpp.html#_ZN8QtCharts9QXYSeries7replaceE7QVectorI7QPointFE)

**EDIT**

I just realized that the assignment operator of QVector gets called in QSplineSeries::replace, which looks like [this](https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtbase/src/corelib/tools/qvector.h.html#_ZN7QVectoraSERK7QVectorIT_E). This means that the internal vector in QSplineSeries copies the QVector I pass in, but I still don't see why the QVector I pass in changes it's address.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've encountered one of the ways in which Qt's containers differ from those of the standard library. Specifically, Qt uses [implicit sharing](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/implicit-sharing.html) and copy-on-write. That means that when a copy of a container is made, both the copy and the original point to the same data. It is only when an attempt is made to change the contents of one of the containers that a deep copy is made. (The container being changed gets a new address for its data, even if it was the original container.)

Let's apply this to your example. First you get stats for your `QVector`. Next you call `QSplineSeries::replace(QVector<QPointF>)`. The point of this function is to copy the provided `QVector` into the data of the `QSplineSeries`. This copy will survive the function's return. (The parameter also creates a copy of the vector – it's not passed by reference – but that copy is destroyed when the function returns.) So when you get to the next line, `vector` is sharing data with another container, specifically the one deep within `chart`. So far, so good.

Checking the size and the capacity of `vector` is still good. But then you use [`operator[]`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qvector.html#operator-5b-5d). This returns a non-constant reference to an element of the vector. That means you can write to it. It doesn't matter whether or not you actually write to it. The object has no way of knowing what you will do with the reference, so it must prepare for a potential write. Since the data is shared, a deep copy is triggered. The data in `vector` is copied to a new chunk of memory that you can overwrite without affecting `chart`. Hence the memory address changes.

If you want to accomplish your analysis without triggering a deep copy, change `&vector[0]` to `&vector.at(0)` or to `vector.constData()`. These provide `const`-qualified access to the data, so they do not trigger a deep copy.

*Note: The version of `operator[]` used by a `const QVector` returns a constant reference, so that will not trigger a deep copy. The non-`const` nature of `vector` is a factor here.*

Comment: You are right. I was not aware that the deep copy was made when calling any non-const method that can touch the internally stored data, even when it is not written to/modified. Thanks for clearing that up!