# C++: passing a pointer to a class in a function results in data copy?

Tags: c++, qt, pointers, qt5

In my Qt5 application I have a class 'Image' containing a 1D vector with the pixel values, and a member function which subtracts a reference image, likes this:

```
class Image {
public:

   QVector<float> pixels;

   void subtract(Image *refImage) {
      long i = 0;
      for (auto &pix : pixels) {
          pix -= refImage->pixels[i];
          ++i;
      }
   }
}
```

I also have a Class 'Data', containing a pointer to the reference image:

```
class Data {
public:
   Image* refImage;
}
```

Finally, in my main function I subtract the reference image from the image like this:

```
int main() {
   ...
   Image *image = new Image(args);
   Data *referenceData = new Data(args);

   image->subtract(referenceData->refImage);
   ...
}
```

Since I'm passing a pointer to subtract() I do not expect a copy of refImage to be made. However, what I observe, is that for every call to subtract() the memory footprint of my application increases by roughly the size of 'refImage'. I don't understand this. I thought by passing a pointer to a class to a function, I'm avoiding copies being made?

Comment: Passing a pointer will not copy the pointed-to thing. Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: There is no obvious copy of any significant data here. Either there is something wrong with how you measure your memory footprint or there is a problem with code you haven't shown. Please share how you determined your memory footprint and a [MCVE].

Comment: In `image->subtract(referenceData->refImage);` you appear to be passing an uninitialized pointer `referenceData->refImage` by value to `Image::subtract`.  Or is `referenceData->refImage` initialized somewhere else?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does the address of QVector change when size() has not surpassed capacity() after calling QXYSeries::replace()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57931574/why-does-the-address-of-qvector-change-when-size-has-not-surpassed-capacity) -- If you don't see how it applies to your situation, I can adapt my answer there to your situation.

Comment: I have a Linux box with 64 GB RAM and determine the memory footprint from /proc/meminfo. When I comment out the line `pix -= refImage->pixels[i];` in `subtract()`, the system uses about 2GB less, corresponding quite well with the overall number of times this line is called. Also, all QVectors are initialized and filled before I get into this part of the code. Extracting a minimum working example will take some time.

Comment: @JaMIt: Your explanation makes sense, but the implementation (changing `pixels[i]` by `pixels.at(i)`) does not seem to affect my memory consumption. And why doesn't the deep copy run out of scope when the end of my `subtract()` function is reached?

Comment: @MischaSchirmer The deep copy does not run out of scope because `*refImage` does not run out of scope. The theory is that you make a (shallow) copy somewhere else, but the memory impact is not seen until a deep copy is triggered (by `subtract`).

Comment: Thanks, JaMiT! I will go over my code and try to isolate this place. Perhaps I can can also pull out a min working example.

Answer (score 1):

You've probably encountered one of the ways in which Qt's containers differ from those of the standard library. Specifically, Qt uses [implicit sharing](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/implicit-sharing.html) and copy-on-write. That means that when a copy of a container is made, both the copy and the original point to the same data. It is only when an attempt is made to change the contents of one of the containers that a deep copy is made. (While your trimmed example does not show a copy being made, it is rather likely that copying is going on somewhere in your real code.)

Let's apply this to your example. When you access the data of the reference image, you have a non-`const` `QVector`, and you access the data via [`operator[]`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qvector.html#operator-5b-5d). This returns a non-constant reference to an element of the vector. That means you can write to it. It doesn't matter whether or not you actually write to it. The object has no way of knowing what you will do with the reference, so it must prepare for a potential write. Since the data (presumably) is shared, a deep copy is triggered. The data in `refImage->pixels` is copied to a new chunk of memory that you can overwrite without affecting whatever copy happens to be out there. Hence, more memory is consumed.

If you want to accomplish your task without triggering a deep copy, change `refImage->pixels[i]` to `refImage->pixels.at(i)` or perhaps `refImage->pixels.value(i)` since you don't check how large the reference vector is. Alternatively, declare `refImage` to be `Image const *` so that the the version of `operator[]` used by a `const QVector` is used; this version returns a constant reference, which will not trigger a deep copy.

*Adapted from [my answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57932099).*

Comment: Dear JaMit, 

following your advice, I have changed the member function to ` void subtract(QVector<float> const &pixels)`, and the line in the `for` loop to `pix -= pixels.at(i);`, but I don't observe a change in memory usage.

Comment: Hmm... it's possible that the shallow copy occurring somewhere else is of `image` rather than of `referenceData`. Based on the information in your question, the memory impact should be similar. That would not be as readily fixable in `subtract` because you want `*this` to change. Still, a test for this hypothesis would be to change `image->subtract(referenceData->refImage);` to `referenceData->refImage->subtract(referenceData->refImage);`. While this is not the functionality you want, a reduction in the memory impact should mean that there is a shallow copy of `image` somewhere else.

Comment: I probably found it. I'm using an openMP parallelized for loop to execute the subtract() function for all images. With a single CPU everything is fine, but with more than one CPU data copies are made by the individual threads and not released anymore when the threads end. I was convinced that the problem was how I pass classes in functions. My apologies to everyone who replied, your suggestions helped to significantly improve my Qt5 code, by using const declarations and replacing "operator[]" with ".at()". I will close this topic once I figured out the openMP memory handling.