# Reference to a vector element become invalid after n iterations

Tags: c++, qt

Program stop occur in this line

```
guess = secret;
```

From that, I guess that reference is broken, because if I change reference to simple value

```
const string secret = word_list[idx_word];
```

the program finishes correctly. So, my question is why this happen. The word_list is not changed/resided in loop.

Erorr occur on 392 iteration.

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QFile>
#include <QDir>
#include <QVector>
#include <cmath>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <set>
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

bool debug = true;

const int COUNT = 5;
string MASK_FULL_MATCH(COUNT, 'o');

const string getMask(const string& word, const string& answer) {
    if (word.size() != COUNT || answer.size() != COUNT) {
        cout << word.size() << " " << answer.size() << endl;
    }

    char mask[5];
    bool visited[5];
    for (int i = 0; i < COUNT; i++) {
        mask[i] = 'x';
        visited[i] = false;
    }

    // find correct letters
    for(int i = 0; i < COUNT; i++){
        if (word[i] == answer[i]){
            mask[i] = 'o';
            visited[i] = true;
        }
    }

    // find present letters
    for (int i = 0; i < COUNT; i++){
        if (mask[i] != 'o'){
            for (int j = 0; j < COUNT; j++) {
                if (answer[j] == word[i] && !visited[j]) {
                    mask[i] = '-';
                    visited[j] = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return string(mask, COUNT);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QString pathToFile = QString("C:/Users/Ivan/Desktop/w_assets/w") + QString::number(COUNT) + QString("_entropy.txt");

    QFile file(pathToFile);
    if (!file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly | QIODevice::Text))
        return -2;

    QTextStream in(&file);
    QVector<string> word_list;
    while (!in.atEnd()) {
      QString line = in.readLine();
      word_list.append(line.split(QChar(' '))[0].toStdString());
    }
    file.close();

    for (int idx_word = 0; idx_word < word_list.size(); idx_word++) {
        const string &secret = word_list[idx_word];
        cout << secret << '\t';
    }

    int total = 0;
    for (int idx_word = 0; idx_word < word_list.size(); idx_word++) {
        const string &secret = word_list[idx_word];
        cout << "NEW SECRET " << secret << endl;
        QVector<string> possible_answers = word_list;
        for (int row = 0; row < 6; row++) {
            string guess;
            if (row == 0) {
                guess = word_list[0];
            }
            else {
                cout << "before broken secret\n";
                guess = secret;
                cout << "after broken secret\n";
                cout << "row " << row << "; GUESS " << guess << endl;
            }

            debug = true;
            string mask = getMask(guess, secret);
            debug = false;
            cout << "MASK: " << mask << endl;
            if (mask == MASK_FULL_MATCH) {
                break;
            }

            QVector<string> new_possible_answers;
            for (const auto& pa : possible_answers) {
                if (getMask(guess, pa) == mask) {
                    new_possible_answers.append(pa);
                }
            }

            possible_answers = new_possible_answers;
            cout << "NEW POSSIBLE WORDS SIZE " << possible_answers.size() << endl;
        }

    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If a vector needs to reallocate memory, I.e. you push_back() when size() == capacity() then all references will be invalidated as it moves memory. You can reserve() before adding to the vector to make sure this doesn't happen if you know how big it needs to be before hand

Comment: @Justin I know, but I don't see line of code where vector neeed to reallocate memory.

Comment: Does the problem go away if you replace `QVector` with `std::vector`? I suspect the lazy copy could come into play.

Comment: By the way, your [mre] seems to be longer than it needs to be. Have you tried replacing `getMask()` with `string getMask() { return ""; }`? If that does not cause the error to go away -- maybe it would since UB is weird, but if it does not -- then that can reduce your example by a significant chunk.

Comment: @JaMiT yes, if I replace `QVector` with `std::vector` example works correctly. So, why `QVector` don't work? Because of lazy copy? Ok, but why word_list is reallocated, and not `possible_words` or `new_possible_words`

Comment: Does QVector.append make a copy or just hold onto a reference? If it holds onto a reference, that varaible is long out of scope when accessed on the line with the issue. (easiest to just go take a look at the function header to be sure)

Comment: @van9petryk First, I apologize for not having time at the moment to carefully analyze your code and point out exactly what is going on. However, I can point you to [an answer I wrote on the subject](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57932099/) -- maybe it will help? At the moment, I don't see that other question being a true duplicate, just related and possibly helpful. No guarantees. ;) (When I find time later, I'll try to remember to come back to this.)

Comment: My guess is that one or more of the strings being checked or compared against has length less than 5.   This will cause undefined behaviour in `getMask()` which has loops that access the first five elements in the strings, so runs past the end of such strings.    A common symptom of undefined behaviour is that a code change which seems to do nothing actually changes how the program behaves.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

word_list[0]; - this is a non-const operation in a QVector (see [documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qvector.html#operator-5b-5d), there is even a note about the possible detach) and since the reference count of your word_list is two due to the copy to possible_answers some lines above, the container has to do a detach and therefore your reference goes out of scope.
If you work with references on Qt containers you have to make sure to either have a reference count of 1 or only use const-access to the container (e.g. by creating a const ref to the container -> const auto &const_word_list = word_list; guess = const_word_list [0])

Comment: Hmmm, `QVector`: avoid.

Comment: better: make sure to know the class you're working with and read the documentation instead simply guess and assume something which is wrong in the end.

Comment: OK, note to self: avoid `QVector` :)  I can't say I like that behaviour, although I assume there's a reason for it.

Comment: The reason is to avoid uneeded copying of the container data.

Comment: But why would `word_list[0]` copy anything?  In the case of `std::vector`, certainly, it returns a reference.  Perhaps `QVector` is different, but that would be a design flaw, IMO.

Comment: Again: because word_list[0] returns a **reference** - not a **const reference**. Therefore the container must be sure that no other container references it and needs to detach if there is another one. Properly explained in the Qt container documentation and a 'normal' thing when working with implicit shared containers.

Comment: Still don't like it.  `std::string` abandoned copy-on-write long ago, for example, because it's basically not wise to attempt that kind of sorcery outside the kernel.  Some light reading:

https://gist.github.com/alf-p-steinbach/c53794c3711eb74e7558bb514204e755